# Creating custom initialization for Swift Types

Tags: swift

I would like to make custom initialization for Swift Types. Therefore, I tested on 2 different Types to see the results.

For example, I wanted make a custom initialization for `String`. I could not find any initialization that takes a `String` for initialization. The best choice that I thought of was using `LosslessStringConvertible` for name -- that should get `String` value to work.

```
extension String {
    init<T:LosslessStringConvertible>(name: T) {
        self.init(name)
    }
}
```

My another try was with CGColor, but for unknown reason for me this code does not build:

```
extension CGColor {
    init(_ value: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: value, green: value, blue: value, alpha: value)
    }
}
```

the error:

> Designated initializer cannot be declared in an extension of 'CGColor'

**My Goal: Which steps should I take to be sure my custom initialization method would be correct and working for Swift Types?**

Comment: The first initializer already exists on String `.init(_ value: LosslessStringConvertible)` Thats the one you are calling inside your own initializer.

Comment: Yes, I chose it because I found it as initialization way for String, I was thinking to use `CustomStringConvertible` instead as well. But I am not sure which one is better for name.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. String has all initializers you might need

Comment: CustomStringConvertible is more generic than LosslessStringConvertible. String already have one for that as well `String(describing: )`

Comment: "Not sure what you are trying to achieve" according to question trying make a custom initialization for String Type which name would get String value to make initialization .

Comment: As I said String already have both of them

Comment: I can use this one as well, `extension String { init<T: CustomStringConvertible>(name2: T) { self.init(String(describing: name2)) } }`

Comment: Don't get me wrong but those extra initializers are pointless

Comment: Regarding your CGColor attempt you can't create convenience initializers for Core Foundation types. CGColor is not a Swift type

Comment: @LeoDabus: "Don't get me wrong but those extra initializers are pointless" they are test and sample, I have to show my approach to receive an answer, for sure I do not need those initialization for String, but in some case we can use it.

Comment: @swiftPunk I’m noticing a general trend in your questions: you provide non-working solutions to unknown problems (you haven’t told us what the concrete problem is you’re trying to solve), and ask us to somehow make them work. Without understanding what problem you’re trying to solve, or what your motivations are, we can’t really help. We’re forced to guess, then you get frustrated that the suggestions you get don’t match your understanding of your secret problem

Comment: The answer to all of your questions is the same. Get employed by apple to work on the swift compiler team. Then go and add these new features that you seem to be looking for that don’t currently exist. That will literally solve all the questions that you have answered.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, this is because some Foundation types implemented in Objective-C are not Classes, but some other structures, in this case, CGColor is probably a C struct. This is mostly hidden from you in Swift unless you dive deep.

Your String example works because it is a class and can implement an init in an extension.

As far as steps you can take, you can attempt to make wrapper classes/structs for these somewhat primitive objects.

Such as

```
struct JnPDxPoint {
   let value: CGPoint
   init(_ value: CGPoint) {
     self.value = value
   }
}
```

Which would allow you to do

```
extension JnPDxPoint {
    init(_ value: CGFloat) {
        self.init(.init(red: value, green: value, blue: value, alpha: value))
    }
}
```

On a more specific level, you could just use UIColor or NSColor and convert to a CGColor as needed.

Comment: I did not asked for custom Type! please read question before answering! I asked for Swift Types!

Comment: @swiftPunk The point of this answer is that you _cannot_ create initializers for arbitrary types because they _aren't_ all Swift types. `CGColor`, for instance, in your question, _will not work_ because it is not defined in Swift itself (but imported from C). So the best that you can do _is_ to create a custom type which _contains_ a `CGColor` and implement your initializer on that. If that does not work, please update your question to be clearer about the specifics of what you need.

Comment: Then, the answer with that restriction is -- you can't extend a lot of CoreFoundation types -- which under the hood are not swift types at all.

Comment: I'm amused and confused by the fact that my user name is in the type...